# is there a way to fetch records from mysql beyond ArrayList max size

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am not able to add fetched records to `ArrayList` object as `ArrayList` has a maximum size of `Integer.max` and query to `mysql` database is retrieving a way too many records than `Integer.max`.

I was into `spring boot` project. We needed a solution to fetch records from `mysql` database using `spring data jpa`. Below is my code to fetch records:

```
@Override
public List<HtsLogs> getAllRecords(String from, String to) {
    System.out.println(from+"                "+to);
    List<HtsLogs> listHtsLogs = new ArrayList<HtsLogs>();
    try {
        String sql =  "SELECT em.* FROM local_backup.hts_logs as em  where em.created_date between ? and ? order by em.created_date desc ;";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql,HtsLogs.class);
        query.setParameter(1, from);
        query.setParameter(2, to);
        listHtsLogs = query.getResultList();
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("exception HtsLOGS exception HtsLOGS exception HtsLOGS ");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listHtsLogs;
}
```

I expected to accumulate all records at once in arraylist object, but due to max size, I am not able to do so. I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` error. Is there any solution to this..

Comment: we already know there would be a large very large amount of data coming from mysql.. we are migrating it to `mongodb`

Comment: The max numer of elements in a list is 2^31. Suppose each element of the list takes just 16 bytes (that's the minimum for a completely empty object: less than what an Integer takes). You would thus need 16 * 2^31 bytes, i.e. 32GB to hold that list in memory. Do you have 32GB of heap size? Now your ojects are probably much larger. Let's say each is just 160 bytes (which is still quite small). You would need 320 GB of heap. Do you have that? Loading everything in memory doesn't make any sense.

Comment: try using batch concept. just a guideline here http://websystique.com/springbatch/spring-batch-read-from-mysql-database-and-write-to-a-csv-file/

Comment: BTW, I doubt you have that many rows in your table. An OutOfMemoryError means that you're out of memory, not that you're trying to fill a list with more elements than its max size. Still, loading everything in memory is not a good strategy, and using JPA is probably not either, but you haven't told us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your efforts here.. they are informative to us. we have run the jar using `nohup java -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx6144m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m springmongo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &`. HtsLogs table in mysql is holding too much data to handle.. we needed a utility to store those in our back up mongodb instance.

Comment: we are trying to migrate our data from mysql to mongodb

Comment: we were fail to import export scripts to and fro mysql to mongo using csv file formats

Comment: You don't need to have all your entities in memory to do that. You just need one in memory at a time. Use JDBC, make sure to configure the driver to not load everything in memory (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html), iterate through the resultset, and for each row or batch of some rows, add it/them to MongoDB).

Comment: 6GB is not enough if it's really that many entries. Try increasing the Xmx value (a lot), or see aka-zobar's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Loading everything into memory is what causes the `OutOfMemoryError`, not the ArrayList max size limitation.

For such cases, Spring Data JPA provides the mechanism of **pagination**. Here is an example:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import java.util.List;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

  public List<Employee> findByDept(String deptName, Pageable pageable);
}
```

where [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) is an interface for pagination information.

Answer (score 0):

If increasing the Xmx is not enough or not possible, and pagination also isn't an option, you could check the HtsLogs object. It may be able to optimize it to be more memory efficient by selecting different data types for its fields.

Remember, anything that is suboptimal in that object will be multiplied for every entry in that list, and if you truly have a number of entries of such a magnitude that will matter a lot.

Comment: S O L V E D. While inserting data in `Mongo` DB I was using `GridFS`. In order to read from flat file I was using `InputStream`. I forgot to make it `close`. So now problem solved.